# Underlining greek letters with soulutf8 and compiling with LuaLaTeX

Tags: greek, soul, underline

I would like to use the features of [`soulutf8`](https://ctan.org/search/?phrase=soulutf8) and compile a document containing greek letters with LuaLaTeX. However, this approach seems to gobble the letters that I chose for underlining. What can be done?

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{soulutf8}

\begin{document}

ὦ \ul{Ἀχιλεῦ}, Πηλῆος υἱέ, μέγα φέρτατ’ \ul{Ἀχαιῶν},

\end{document}
```

Comment: I tested the solution proposed in the duplicate question and it seems to work. Note that you don't need `soulutf8`, just `soul`.

Comment: Maybe a little bit different, as I needed FreeMono instead of TeX Gyre Cursor. The proposed solution still gobbled the ῦ.

Comment: Yes, I'll change the code: FreeMono has a better coverage of glyphs.

Comment: Still a duplicate? I didn´t find the question as I didn´t search for spacing out or Hungarian.

Comment: The problem is exactly the same.

Comment: Closing as duplicate doesn't mean it was a bad question. It will remain on the site and possibly help other readers.